How do I create and use a map in Databricks SQL
I want to create a map and use it in the same SQL query. I am trying something similar to
select sample_map[t1.col1], t1.col2 from table1 as t1, (select map(1,2,3,4)) as sample_map group by t1.col2;


Check below sql query.
SELECT 
    m.s_map[t1.col1] AS m_col1,
    t1.col2 AS col2
FROM table1 t1,
(SELECT map(1,2,3,4) as s_map) as m
GROUP BY col2, m_col1

